# Paste file in new file in python

Tags: python, file, copy-paste, extends

Is there a way to just open/create `filehandle = open( "example.bin", "wb")` and extend this file with an existing file?

I think about something like the `.extend` from function for lists
Like so:

```
filehandle = open( "example.bin", "wb")
filehande.extend(existing_file.bin)
```

I know that i can read the existing file and write that to a variable/list and "paste" it in the new file but im curious if there is an easier option like this...

Comment: filehandle is just a file object, and not a list

Comment: I know, if you read my question twice im asking about a similar method.

Comment: `cat file1 file2 > file3` Run it on terminal.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thats possible but No option for me.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nope but i Want to solve it in Python

Comment: Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) you can do stuff like this:  `from pathlib import Path; p1, p2 = Path('path1'), Path('path2'); p1.write_bytes(p1.read_bytes() + p2.read_bytes())` which appends the contents of 'path2' to 'path1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('original', 'a') as out_file, open('other', 'r') as ins_file:
    out_file.write(ins_file.read())
```

This will append the contents of `other` onto `original`. If you're dealing with binary data you can change the mode on each to `ab` and `rb`.

If the contents of the file are large you can [do it in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/519653/2714534) too.

Comment: This will actually __replace__ the content of `original` with `other`. Opening an existing file a in write ("w") mode immediatly erases the file's content. To append to an existing file you want to open in append ("a") mode, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge file objects. You can make a list of each file and extended them

`files_combined = list(open("example.bin", "wb")) + list(open("file_2"))`

Will return a list with all the lines in `file_2` appended to `file_1`, but in a new list. You can then save it to a new file, or overwrite one of the files.